# Three.js - How to change a texture of a 3D model in only one specific point?

Tags: three.js, textures

Three.js - How to change a texture of a 3D model in only one specific point so that not all the model changes texture ?? I have the json file of the model if anyone would like to see it. TIA!

Comment: by all means post the json file of the model

Comment: I will send it to your private email ;)

Comment: can you post a portion of it here ? Like what fields you have, the first 10 values etc.

Comment: I mean, everything has been said, you need blender, maya, 3ds max or something in order to 'detach' the sleeves into another mesh or a sub mesh. But, still there is a chance that you might have material ids in the file.

Comment: Thanks a million Pailhead. To be honest with you I am asking this on behalf of our programmer who doesn't speak English. We will be having a Skype tomorrow 15 Oct if you could join for a few minutes, the programmer can show you the file. Please contact me via Twitter: @GrafosDesign Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial` -- use this to apply different materials to different parts of a single mesh. `MeshFaceMaterial` lets you have a group of different "regular" materials, each of which may have a different textures, and then assign on a per-poly basis. The assignment happens in the geometry object.  See http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshFaceMaterial for docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem we have now is how can we find the coordinates in the 3D model code of the specific parts we want to change textures. For instance if we have imported model of shirt how can we find the coordinates in the code of the 3D model to change the texture of only the sleeves? Thanks again for your help

Comment: You would be best doing this in the original modeling program (tag the sleeves as a different material, or in their own layer, etc -- depending on the program). Know the *meaning* of a mesh is difficult to do (like: get-your-PhD difficult) without human intervention.

Comment: get-your-PhD difficult - best explanation

Comment: indeed PhD-difficult! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link!!